# how to enable stream module in nginx container

Tags: mongodb, nginx, devops, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to proxy mongodb behind nginx. And I came across following code for same purpose.

### My question is, how can I enable "stream" module in nginx?

```
stream {
    server {
        listen 27020;
        proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
        proxy_timeout 20s;
        proxy_pass    mongodb_host;
    }

    upstream mongodb_host{
        server xx.xxx.xxx.xx:27017;
    }
}
```

Comment: which protocol did you connect to mongo server , http or https ?

Comment: mongodb connection happens over tcp calls..nginx will get the request and forward to mongo as it is, without adding http protocols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically recompiling using the --with-stream option is required, as per the nginx docs. Fortunately there are plenty of existing images for that purpose. I've used this one personally: https://hub.docker.com/r/tekn0ir/nginx-stream

If using compose, your docker-compose.yml file would look something like this -

```
version: '3'  
services:  
    service1:  
        ...  
    service2:  
        ...  
    nginx:  
        image: tekn0ir/nginx-stream:latest  
        ports:   
            - "27020:27020"   
        volumes:   
            - /usr/local/nginx/conf/http:/opt/nginx/http.conf.d
            - /usr/local/nginx/conf/stream:/opt/nginx/stream.conf.d
```

Create 1 or more files in the "/usr/local/nginx/conf/stream" directory containing your code `stream { ... }` . Config file names just need to end with the ".conf" extension. Then you can create any http config files in "/usr/local/nginx/conf/http".

Answer (score -3):

Straight from the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html):

"The ngx_stream_core_module module is available since version 1.9.0. This module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the --with-stream configuration parameter."